# How to save JSON data to new JSON file through iterating using AJAX and PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, ajax

I have simple movies editor with the sidebar in which user just drag and drop the element to the right side user can edit this element as they wish and save data to JSON, I want when the user clicks to save it should create a new file and save to it new data.

so far here is what I have

HTML

```
        <div class="col-2 save-details">
          <div id="save-block">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-save">Save</button>
          </div>
        </div>
```

here is  js to save the file

```
var moviesblocks =null;

$(document).ready(function(){

$.getJSON('moviesblocks.json', function (data) {

    moviesblocks = data.moviesblocks;
    console.log(moviesblocks);

});

$("#main-btn-save").on("click", function () {

    var moviesparams = JSON.stringify({
        moviesblocks: moviesblocks
    });

    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                moviesparams: moviesparams
            },
            url: 'save_movies_block.php',
            success: function (data) {
                    $('#msg').html(data).fadeIn('slow');
                    $('#msg').delay(2000).fadeOut('slow');
            },
            error: function () {
                    $('#error-msg').html(data).fadeIn('slow');
                    $('#error-msg').delay(2000).fadeOut('slow');
            }
    });

    console.log(moviesparams);
});

})
```

Here is php file to handle the process

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['moviesparams'])){
    $moviesparams = json_decode($_POST['moviesparams']);
    // do whatever checks you need on $moviesparams to verify valid data
    $success = file_put_contents("moviesblocks.json", json_encode($moviesparams));
    if($success === false){
        echo "sorry , something is wrong";
        die();
    }else{
        echo "Data successfully saved";
        die();
    }
} else {
    echo "nic";
}

$data=file_get_contents("data.json");
$result=json_decode($data);
?>
```

As you can see now after user clicks save it save to this file

```
moviesblocks.json
```

Now I want when a user clicks save, it should save to new file 
something like `moviesblocks1.json` instead of moviesblocks.json

Here is a live demo [live demo](https://videomill-bot.audiencevideo.com/editor/)

How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: Seems like a database would suit this just dandy

Comment: Simply a new file for every save? Something like `$success = file_put_contents(uniqid() . "_moviesblocks.json", json_encode($moviesparams));` 

Or maybe do you want a new file "per user"?

Comment: Right now I don't have user profile anyway this will be used by one user it's not commercial, I just want when user clicks the block to edit it should save it with different name , I will try what u have suggested , I will get back to you, here is live demo https://videomill-bot.audiencevideo.com/editor/

Answer (score 2):

If you dont wanna use database, you need to create one more file to maintain file version numbers. Each time you wanna create new file, get the latest version number from this version.txt file and append it to filename. Eg : moviesblocks1.json, moviesblocks2.json.

After creating new file,  update the version from version.txt. This will help you to create new version number next time.

Comment: Dont forget to FLOCK that `version.txt` file and use it to serialize access or you will get version number crashes and loose data

Comment: @RiggsFolly — It's a shame that tools specifically designed for dealing with this problem don't exist. If only someone would invent something. They could call it *the database*.

Comment: @Quentin [What a absolutely SUPER idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56854939/how-to-save-json-data-to-new-json-file-through-iterating-using-ajax-and-php#comment100260145_56854939) Patent it quick

Comment: Hi guys am new to PHP here is live demo https://videomill-bot.audiencevideo.com/editor/ her is repository https://github.com/throne1986/editor can some one help me on This? Am struggling with this, just clone it and run in xamp